# How can I get verbose eosio_assert error messages on cleos command line (not http api)

Tags: cleos, error

How can I get error messages in the console to be verbose? In particular all eosio_assert fails are coming back vanilla 'eosio assert failure'. 
I've added --verbose-http-errors to my config.ini and added -v to my cleos alias but no luck.
I'm using the docker image running Debian 8 (Jesse)